# Не работает функция в цикле python

Tags: python, многопоточность, telebot, pyttsx3

Хочу написать программу, которая будет взаимодействовать с телеграмм.

**Принцип работы:** Я пишу боту в телеграмме сообщение, программа на компьютере читает сообщение (библиотека *telebot*) и воспроизводит его синтезатором речи (библиотека *pyttsx3*).

**Проблема:** Первое сообщение читается и озвучивается, на последующие выдаёт ошибку. Я так понимаю тут проблема с потоками или циклами, но как это исправить не понимаю.

**Code:**

```python
import telebot
from telebot import types
import pyttsx3

token = "xxx"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

def say(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_messages(message):
    say(message.text)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

**Error:**

```
2022-02-04 00:33:01,090 (__init__.py:615 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: run loop already started"
2022-02-04 00:33:01,091 (__init__.py:617 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 611, in infinity_polling
    self.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 658, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 720, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 680, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\venv\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\main.py", line 23, in repeat_messages
    say(message.text)
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\main.py", line 15, in say
    engine.runAndWait()
  File "C:\Users\caleb\Python\czAudioPad\venv\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 177, in runAndWait
    raise RuntimeError('run loop already started')
RuntimeError: run loop already started
"
```

*Сильно не ругайтесь, пожалуйста, если решение очевидное)*

Comment: В одном ответе на английском SO советуют после `engine.runAndWait()` делать так: `if engine._inLoop: engine.endLoop()`

Comment: Поставил `if engine._inLoop: engine.endLoop()` в конце функции `say`, выдаёт ту же ошибку, попробовал поставить в начале функции, теперь 2 раза озвучивает, а последующие разы нет, но ошибки никакие в консоль не выдаёт.